# Asset pipeline, compass font-face and eot?iefix call to the font

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, font-face, compass-sass, asset-pipeline, sprockets

I am trying to use a Compass font-face mixin, which contains the inclusion of
*.eot?iefix

My app/assets/fonts contains all the font types needed, including .eot.

When I try to run assets:precompile the task fails saying something like:
webfont.eot?iefix isn't precompiled

Do you know the possible solution for this problem?

It runs with no error in case I have config.assets.compile = true, but as I've understood it's better not to use it on production.

Answer (score 10):

You can do it with pure **Scss** too:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'DroidSans';
  src: url(font-path('DroidSans-webfont.eot'));
  src: url(font-path('DroidSans-webfont.eot') + '?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
       url(font-path('DroidSans-webfont.woff')) format('woff'),
       url(font-path('DroidSans-webfont.ttf')) format('truetype'),
       url(font-path('DroidSans-webfont.svg') + '#DroidSansRegular') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

Comment: instead of `url(font-path())`, we can use `font-url()`

Comment: I believe you can now. At the time there was a conflict between Sass helpers and Rails helpers.

Answer (score 4):

I've just solved this problem with a little (supported) hack.

I've created a new css file `font.css.erb` and place `@import "font"` in the place of the `@font-face` declaration.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'SketchBlockBold';
    src: font_url('font/sketch_block-webfont.eot');
    src: url('<%= asset_path('font/sketch_block-webfont.eot')+"?#iefix" %>') format('embedded-opentype'),
         font_url('font/sketch_block-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         font_url('font/sketch_block-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('<%= asset_path('font/sketch_block-webfont.svg')+"#SketchBlockBold" %>') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Note the use of the asset path, and the concatenation of the special file endings.

Comment: why did you use both the `font-url` and `url` declarations? whats the difference?

Comment: It's because url() isn't a asset pipeline function but font_url() is. In this case I'm basically replacing the font_url() magic with the stuff in erb

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Code works perfectly fine locally, but `rake assets:precompile` falls back to the same error: `fontname.eot isn't precompiled`
What could be a problem, how do you think?

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be a known issue https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/3045
Using config.assets.compile = true for now.