# Asset pipeline issues with @font-face eot?iefix

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails-3.1, font-face, asset-pipeline, sprockets

Im working on a rails app trying to configure fonts with rails 3.1 and the asset pipeline.

I just took a look at this post

[Asset pipeline, compass font-face and eot?iefix call to the font](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7699663/asset-pipeline-compass-font-face-and-eotiefix-call-to-the-font)

and using the example i get a syntax issue from sass.

My code is as follows:

```
/* @font-face kit by Fonts2u (http://www.fonts2u.com) */ 
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Coamei Bold';
  src: font_url('fonts/COAMEI_B.eot');
  src: url('<%= asset_path('fonts/COAMEI_B.eot')+"?#iefix" %>') format('embedded-opentype'),
       font_url('fonts/COAMEI_B.woff') format('woff'),
       font_url('fonts/COAMEI_B.ttf') format('truetype'),
       url('<%= asset_path('COAMEI_B.svg')+"#Coamei-Bold" %>') format('svg');
  font-weight:normal;
  font-style:normal;
}
```

For some reason i get the error

Sass::SyntaxError: Invalid CSS after "...'fonts/COAMEI_B": expected ")", was ".eot')+"?#iefix..."

Is there something im missing in my css file. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What's the name of the file the code is in?

Comment: its stored in fonts.css.scss in the assets/fonts directory. I also have the file included correctly in the application.css file. Its odd cant spot any differences between the way most seem to be setting this up.

Comment: rubbish, just spotted the issue. Seems to be the single quotes and double quotes mix up. doh!

Comment: hmmmm odd seems to have solved the syntax error. Still no fonts though although i guess this could be my setup

Comment: not sure i understand, how can it be both erb and scss. Not sure im understanding how sass hooks into rails asset pipeline etc really